# Easy Navigation Between Stackoverflow Family-Sites

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, usability

Just accidentally discovered MetaSOFlow today - wouldn't it be wise to create a header listing all of SOFlow's sister sites at the top of each site to allow for better discovery?

#### Update:

I've created [a greasemonkey script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/842/stackoverflow-sister-sites/905#905) to do this for now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the wasted screenestate to the left of the login bar might be used for linking to the other sites...Right now, there are only three sites (SO, SF, SU) and meta. However, I think a dropdown menu linking to the three main sites might be useful to some people, as long as it isn't distracting.

Comment: ++ I agree completely. A nice drop down would serve very well.

Answer (score 5):

There is one at the bottom of the page.

There might be a better place for it somewhere on the page, but it's definitely there already (and the "feedback always welcome" link also directs here as well).

Comment: Oh, did the switch happen within the last couple days? I think I ended up on uservoice from the feedback link yesterday or so.

Comment: The blog post about meta went up yesterday http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/cmon-get-meta/

Comment: Ah, that explains why I was in the dark :)

Answer (score 2):

We now **sort the gen-u-wine sites list by the amount of reputation you have on each site.**

[image]

You must have a minimum of **200 rep** on any given site to have it appear in anything other than random order, though.

Answer (score 1):

The links are at the bottom. I don't think moving the links upward would be a good choice, as I wouldn't expect most typical users to care. They want answers to questions. The more "dedicated" users who are interested in the overall community, I would expect to follow the blog and other related things that would help direct them to new areas/features as they are added.

Comment: In my experience, people tend to ignore footers, discounting them as where the copyright notice, terms, and other lawyer bits go...

Comment: I fall into that category - unless I know otherwise before hand.

Comment: Right but the purpose of SO is not to funnel people to meta, so I don't think the link needs to be obvious.

Comment: We aren't talking about meta, I don't think, but Server Fault, Super User, and other "main" sites.

Comment: Having a list of sister sites isn't the same as "funneling" users to any particular site. It's a convention commonly used online to allow ease of access for the audience.

Answer (score 1):

Created a Greasemonkey script to do this for now:

[Sister-Sites Greasemonkey Concept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/882/sister-sites-greasemonkey-concept)

[image]

Comment: very cool, but it might be possible for the name + badges + rep to get long enough to intersect.

Comment: Yeah; You could replace the lengthy text with icons.