# Sister-Sites Greasemonkey Concept

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, integration

#### Version canceled - Minimalistic version now available.

- [SO-Site Bar (Minimalistic)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2542/so-site-bar-minimalistic)

  [image]

Comment: I gave you my last upvote for the day!

Comment: This is exactly what Jeff and co. should implement, although with slightly more height (to match the user bar thing opposite it) and with considerations of a drop-down menu if the number of sites grow. +1 for the effort and (hopefully temporary) solution to navigating the SO family!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes!

These links are already in the footer of the page, but I only noticed these because I was specifically looking for them ("there must be a link to serverfault somewhere..")

They really should be more prominent..

On a pedantic note, you don't need to re-include jQuery because Stackoverflow already uses it, so you can simplify the Greasemoney script a tiny bit and remove..

```
GM_JQ.src = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js';
GM_JQ.type = 'text/javascript';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(GM_JQ);
```

Comment: You're right. Updated.

Answer (score 4):

**Updated to include new Search** (Search Meta/SO/and SF all together)

Adds links to the top, and updates regular search to "Power Search," which will return results from all of the SO sites.

[image]

```
(function(){
  function GM_wait() {
    if(typeof unsafeWindow.jQuery == 'undefined') { 
      window.setTimeout(GM_wait,100); 
    } else { 
      $ = unsafeWindow.jQuery; letsJQuery(); 
    }
  }
  GM_wait();
  function letsJQuery() {
    $("<div></div>")
      .css({"background-color":"#f1f1f1","padding":"5px 10px 5px 10px","position":"fixed"})
      .html($("#footer-sites").clone())
      .prependTo("#header");
    $("#footer-sites:eq(0)").append('<form id="cse-search-box" action="http://www.google.com/cse"><div style="padding:2px 0;text-align:center;"><input type="hidden" value="018205968162215846785:ge5giybfqde" name="cx"/><input type="hidden" value="UTF-8" name="ie"/><input type="text" size="35" name="q" class="textbox" value="power search" maxlength="80" onfocus="if (this.value==\'power search\') this.value=\'\'" tabindex="1" style="background:#ffffff url(/Content/Img/search.png) no-repeat scroll left center; border-color:#cccccc -moz-use-text-color -moz-use-text-color #cccccc; border-style: solid none none solid; border-width: 1px medium medium 1px; margin:0; padding-left:16px;"/></div></form>');
  }
})();
```