# Stack Overflow browser toolbar

Tags: support, stack-overflow, toolbar, browsers

Is there a toolbar for Stack Overflow that can be added to a browser window?

Comment: Browser toolbars are evil!

Answer (score 3):

There are various [GreaseMonkey scripts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3687/greasemonkey-script-ideas-best-of-stackoverflow-greasemoneky-implementations), including [a bar to let you easily switch between sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2542/so-site-bar-minimalistic).

I don't believe there are any "Google toolbar"-style toolbars.

Answer (score 3):

There is in fact a Stack Overflow toolbar for FireFox,
[Stack Overflow Add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/11928)

It has fairly limited functionality at the moment, but it's pretty hard to do much without an API (unless you use GreaseMonkey as already pointed out, although still less than ideal).

Answer (score 1):

What kind of features are you thinking of for a toolbar?  There have been a few META posts on greasemonkey scripts that tweak the UI a bit...

Answer (score 1):

The Powers That Be could get a free one from [Conduit](http://www.conduit.com/) and then also make a few cents everytime someone installs it.

No adware, no spyware. I use it on one of my own sites and people are happy.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [StackOverflow Toolbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216752/firefox-stackoverflow-toolbar). (personally [I don't see the point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216752/firefox-stackoverflow-toolbar/217798#217798).)