# Is it possibile to have link to stackoverflow, serverfault, etc. also in the header?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, hyperlinks, navigation, header

I know that we have them on bottom, but it would be useful for me to have also on top, so that I don't need scroll down to switch between one site and another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We now **sort the gen-u-wine sites list by the amount of reputation you have on each site.**

[image]

You must have a minimum of **200 rep** on any given site to have it appear in anything other than random order, though.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at the [GreaseMonkey toolbar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2542/so-site-bar-minimalistic)?

Comment: thank you for the link Jon, I think that this topic is already "under investigation" by Jeff

Answer (score 1):

I think it would clutter the header with links that most people rarely need due to Bookmarks. That's not to say that I don't use the links at the bottom. I just don't see the need to put them on the top.

Comment: I agree. I don't see the need to replicate information and navigation all over the place when most people who have an interest in moving between sites quickly already have everything saved in their own bookmarks.