# Create a unified bar to easily navigate between linked sites

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

I find myself jumping between stackoverflow, superuser and serverfault to check on my activity.  Unfortunately there's no easy way to do that other than typing in the other domain and browsing there manually.

Now that we have the ability to associate different accounts it would be nice if we could display a bar along the top of the screen that lets you jump directly to the other site.  Additionally the bar can indicate when you have new activity on the other site and your current reputation.

An example of what I'm talking about can be seen on the 37signals apps.  When you have a highrise and a basecamp account you can jump between your linked accounts easily.

Answer (score 2):

The [StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/new-global-inbox/) has a `sites` tab, which lists all Trilogy and SE 2.0 sites.

[image]

All graduated (non-beta) sites are also linked in the footer.

[image]

These links allow for quick and easy switching between SE sites.

Comment: Only non-beta sites have non-beta sites in the footer. Beta sites list other beta sites.

Answer (score 1):

If you are a firefox user, take a look at this greasemonkey script produced by a few of yoru SO buddies....

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           StackOverflow - Themes
// @namespace      StackOverflow
// @include        http://stackoverflow.com/*
// @include        http://meta.stackoverflow.com/*
// @include        http://serverfault.com/*
// ==/UserScript==

(function(){
                function GM_init() {
                                if(typeof unsafeWindow.jQuery == 'undefined') { 
                                                window.setTimeout(GM_wait,100); 
                                } else { 
                                                jQuery_init(unsafeWindow.jQuery);
                                }
                }

                GM_init();

                function changeTheme(url) {
                                for( i = 0; (l = document.getElementsByTagName("link")[i]); i++ ) {
                                                if( l.getAttribute("rel").indexOf("style") >= 0 ) l.disabled = true;
                                }

                                var link = window.document.createElement('link');
                                link.rel = 'stylesheet';
                                link.type = 'text/css';
                                link.href = url;
                                document.getElementsByTagName("HEAD")[0].appendChild(link);
                }

                function jQuery_init($) {
                                var icons = {
                                                so: "data:image/x-icon;base64,AAABAAEAEBAAAAEAIABoBAAAFgAAACgAAAAQAAAAIAAAAAEAIAAAAAAAAAAAABMLAAATCwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAbGxt%2F2xsbf9sbG3%2FbGxt%2F2xsbf9sbG3%2FbGxt%2F2xsbf9sbG3%2FbGxt%2F2xsbf9sbG3%2FbGxt%2F2xsbf8AAAAAAAAAAGxsbf9sbG3%2FbGxt%2F2xsbf9sbG3%2FbGxt%2F2xsbf9sbG3%2FbGxt%2F2xsbf9sbG3%2FbGxt%2F2xsbf9sbG3%2FAAAAAAAAAABsbG3%2FbGxt%2FwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABsbG3%2FbGxt%2FwAAAAAAAAAAbGxt%2F2xsbf8AAAAAbGxt%2F2xsbf9sbG3%2FbGxt%2F2xsbf9sbG3%2FbGxt%2F2xsbf8AAAAAbGxt%2F2xsbf8AAAAAAAAAAGxsbf9sbG3%2FAAAAAGxsbf9sbG3%2FbGxt%2F2xsbf9sbG3%2FbGxt%2F2xsbf9sbG3%2FAAAAAGxsbf9sbG3%2FAAAAAAAAAABsbG3%2FbGxt%2FwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAVHibFE94oDxKeKRkRHiqkUx4ohlsbG3%2FbGxt%2FwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABLeKMPPHixUj54sIQ%2BeLC5Pniw3j54sP8%2FeK%2F%2FQXet%2F0J2q%2F9Ed6k%2BAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAPXiwKkF4rf9BeK3%2FQXit%2F0J3q%2BxFdqnAQ3erhTt7s1Qqg8VSFY3cWQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD94rwlCeKxzRHaqUUR2qis7e7MIAAAAABiM2QwJk%2BhyA5fv4gKX7v8AmfIbAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACZPoGQOX7oIDlu7tBZXs%2FwSX6%2BwJkeqCHXjmTiBy6QIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA%2BR4QICl%2B4kA5fuhgWW7PMGlev%2FBpXr6wSY64MNjOkQJ23lTC9j5PwuZOSBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAElu0JBpXr1QaV6%2F8GlevpBpbrfASY6xcAAAAAK2fkNi5k5PgsZuT4LGbkRAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAaV62wGlet%2BBZbrFQAAAAAAAAAALWTkIi1l5OUsZuT%2FLGbkWAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAALmPkDyxl5MssZuT%2FLGbkewAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAALmPkAixm5K0sZuT%2FLGbkoQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAALmTkAixm5JMsZuT%2FLGbkwCxm5AcAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgAEAAIAB8L%2Bf%2BQAAkAkAAJAJAACfAQAA4AcAAOAHAADggwAA%2FgEAAPABAADwIQAA%2BMP%2F%2F%2F%2BH%2F%2F%2F%2FDwAA%2Fg8AAA%3D%3D",
                                                su: "data:image/x-icon;base64,AAABAAEAEBAAAAEAIABoBAAAFgAAACgAAAAQAAAAIAAAAAEAIAAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADp6ekmoqKhd6Cgn3mgoJ95oaGgeOPj4i79%2Ff0F%2Bei3YPfgn3X34J91%2BOKkb%2Fruy0L9%2FfwH%2F%2F%2F%2FAP%2F%2F%2FwD%2F%2F%2F8Ax8bGVAkIBvoPDgz4T09NyVhXVcHNzcxM%2Ff37CvXTeKjzx0%2FB88dOxO%2B0Eu7vsAb3%2BOChdf7%2B%2FgD%2F%2F%2F8A%2F%2F%2F%2FAMfGxlQJCAX6Kyop3vj4%2BBn9%2Ff0F%2Ff39Af39%2FQD9%2Ff0D%2Ff39Bf39%2FAf21Hmb768A%2FfXQbZ%2F9%2Ff0B%2F%2F%2F%2FAP%2F%2F%2FwDHxsZUCQgF%2Bi0sKt76%2BvoV%2F%2F%2F%2FAP%2F%2F%2FwD%2F%2F%2F8A%2F%2F%2F%2FAP%2F%2F%2FwD%2B%2Fv4B9tiGkO%2BvAP310Gyg%2Fv7%2BAf%2F%2F%2FwD%2F%2F%2F8Ax8bGVAkIBfotLCre%2Bvr6Ff%2F%2F%2FwD%2F%2F%2F8A%2F%2F%2F%2FAP%2F%2F%2FwD%2F%2F%2F8A%2Fv7%2BAfbYhpDvrwD99dBrof79%2FQP%2F%2F%2F8A%2F%2F%2F%2FAMfGxlQJCAX6LSwq3vr6%2BhX%2F%2F%2F8A%2F%2F%2F%2FAP%2F%2F%2FwD%2F%2F%2F8A%2F%2F%2F%2FAP7%2B%2FgD44qVx768C%2BvG%2BMdf89eIx%2Ff39A%2F7%2B%2FgDHxsZUCQgF%2Bi0sKt76%2BvoV%2F%2F%2F%2FAP%2F%2F%2FwD%2F%2F%2F8A%2F%2F%2F%2FAP%2F%2F%2FwD%2B%2Fv4A%2Ffv2E%2FXTdJ%2FvsQj88Lcc6fXScaH8%2BO0ex8bGVAkIBfotLCre%2Bvr6Ff%2F%2F%2FwD%2F%2F%2F8A%2Fv7%2BAP7%2B%2FgD%2B%2Fv4A%2Fv7%2BAP39%2Bgr44aJ577IN%2Bu%2BxCvXzxUjF%2FPbmK8fGxlQJCAX6LSwq3vr6%2BhX%2F%2F%2F8A%2F%2F%2F%2FAPz8%2FAempqV5kZGQivf39xX55bFl77AG9%2FC3Huj668RS%2Ff37Cv7%2B%2FgDHxsZUCQgF%2Bi0sKt76%2BvoV%2F%2F%2F%2FAP%2F%2F%2FwD6%2BfkPRkVE1ignJePv7%2B8r9tiGkO%2BvAP30zWSo%2Ff39Bf%2F%2F%2FwD%2F%2F%2F8Ax8bGVAkIBfotLCre%2Bvr6Ff%2F%2F%2FwD%2F%2F%2F8A%2Ff39APT09Bnx8fAe%2Ff39BvbYhpDvrwD99dBsoP7%2B%2FgH%2F%2F%2F8A%2F%2F%2F%2FAMfGxlQJCAX6LSwq3vr6%2BhX%2F%2F%2F8A%2F%2F%2F%2FAP%2F%2F%2FwD%2F%2F%2F8A%2F%2F%2F%2FAP7%2B%2FgH22ISR768A%2FfXQbZ%2F9%2Ff0B%2F%2F%2F%2FAP%2F%2F%2FwDHxsZUCQgF%2Bi0sKt76%2BvoV%2F%2F%2F%2FAP%2F%2F%2FwD%2F%2F%2F8A%2F%2F%2F%2FAP7%2B%2FgD9%2FPkM88lXtu%2BvAvz33JGD%2Fv7%2BAP%2F%2F%2FwD%2F%2F%2F8Ax8bGVAkIBfoqKSfi7u7uKfT08xL7%2B%2FsG%2Ff39AP379g%2F89uUv9dN3m%2B%2BwBvjxvznQ%2FPjsJP39%2FQD%2F%2F%2F8A%2F%2F%2F%2FAMjIyFMMCwn6CQgG%2FQ8ODPcVFBLzu7u6Xv39%2BwrzyFS977IM8PC4H%2BX21X6X%2FPjrI%2F7%2B%2FgD%2F%2F%2F8A%2F%2F%2F%2FAP%2F%2F%2FwD19fUV0tLSUNHR0FPR0dBT0tLSUPLy8hn9%2Ff0A%2FPfpKfz25iv9%2FPoR%2Fv7%2BAP%2F%2F%2FwD%2F%2F%2F8A%2F%2F%2F%2FAP%2F%2F%2FwD%2F%2F%2F8A%2F%2F8AAIYPAACfxwAAn8cAAJ%2FHAACf5wAAn%2BEAAJ%2FxAACfZwAAnkcAAJ%2FHAACfxwAAn8cAAJ%2BPAACGHwAA%2F%2F8AAA%3D%3D",
                                                sf: "data:image/x-icon;base64,AAABAAEAEBAQAAEABAAoAQAAFgAAACgAAAAQAAAAIAAAAAEABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACwkIABcXLwBcWloAGx2fACMhmAArHewAFiHtAC8s5gAhJOsALSjpADEn6wCtqagA1NLRAN3V1gD%2F%2F%2F8AAAABABABEREAEAAAAAEREQABAQEAARERAAAAAAAAAAAzMzMzMwIiIjMzMzMzAiIiMzMzMzMCIiIAAAAAAAAAAMzMzMzMBVVUzMzMzMwFVVXMzMzMzAVVVQAAAAAAAAAA3d3d3d0Kiqrd3d3d3gqqp93d3d3dCma5AAAAAAAAAAAAIP%2F%2FACD%2F%2FwAg%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FACD%2F%2FwAg%2F%2F8AIP%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwAg%2F%2F8AIP%2F%2FACD%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F8AIP%2F%2FACD%2F%2FwAg%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F",
                                                meta: "data:image/x-icon;base64,AAABAAEAEBAAAAEAIABoBAAAFgAAACgAAAAQAAAAIAAAAAEAIAAAAAAAQAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAbGxs%2F2xsbP9sbGz%2FbGxs%2F2xsbP9sbGz%2FbGxs%2F2xsbP9sbGz%2FbGxs%2F2xsbP9sbGz%2FbGxs%2F2xsbP8AAAAAAAAAAGxsbP9sbGz%2FbGxs%2F2xsbP9sbGz%2FbGxs%2F2xsbP9sbGz%2FbGxs%2F2xsbP9sbGz%2FbGxs%2F2xsbP9sbGz%2FAAAAAAAAAABsbGz%2FbGxs%2FwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABsbGz%2FbGxs%2FwAAAAAAAAAAbGxs%2F2xsbP8AAAAAbGxs%2F2xsbP9sbGz%2FbGxs%2F2xsbP9sbGz%2FbGxs%2F2xsbP8AAAAAbGxs%2F2xsbP8AAAAAAAAAAGxsbP9sbGz%2FAAAAAGxsbP9sbGz%2FbGxs%2F2xsbP9sbGz%2FbGxs%2F2xsbP9sbGz%2FAAAAAGxsbP9sbGz%2FAAAAAAAAAABsbGz%2FbGxs%2FwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAfn5%2BFH9%2FfzyAgIBkgYGBkX9%2FfxhsbGz%2FbGxs%2FwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB%2Ff38OgoKCUoKCgoWCgoK5goKC34KCgv%2BCgoL%2FgYGB%2F4CAgP%2BAgIA%2BAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgoKCKoGBgf%2BBgYH%2FgYGB%2F4CAgO1%2Ff3%2FBgICAhYSEhFSNjY1Sl5eXWAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAIKCggiBgYFygICAUICAgCqEhIQIAAAAAJaWlgydnZ1yoaGh46CgoP%2BioqIaAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAnZ2dGKCgoIOgoKDtn5%2Bf%2F6CgoO2cnJyDjo6OToyMjAIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAJqamgKgoKAkoKCgh5%2Bfn%2FOfn5%2F%2Fn5%2Bf66CgoIOZmZkQiYmJTIODg%2F2EhISBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACgoKAIn5%2Bf1Z%2Bfn%2F%2Bfn5%2Fpn5%2BffKCgoBYAAAAAhYWFNoSEhPmFhYX5hYWFRAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAJ%2Bfn2yfn59%2Bn5%2BfFAAAAAAAAAAAhISEIoSEhOWFhYX%2FhYWFWAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAg4ODDoSEhMuFhYX%2FhYWFegAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAg4ODAoWFha2FhYX%2FhYWFoQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAhISEAoWFhZOFhYX%2FhYWFwYWFhQYAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAgAH%2F%2F4AB%2F%2F%2Bf%2Bf%2F%2FkAn%2F%2F5AJ%2F%2F%2BfAf%2F%2F4Af%2F%2F%2BAH%2F%2F%2Fgg%2F%2F%2F%2FgH%2F%2F%2FAB%2F%2F%2FwIf%2F%2F%2BMP%2F%2F%2F%2BH%2F%2F%2F%2FD%2F%2F%2F%2Fg%2F%2F%2Fw%3D%3D"
                                };

                                console.log(icons);

                                $('#hlinks')
                                  .prepend('<span class="link-separator">|</span>')
                                  .prepend("<a id='mtheme' href='http://meta.stackoverflow.com'><img src='" + icons.meta + "' title='Visit Meta Stack Overflow' style='padding:1px'></a>")
                                  .prepend('<span class="link-separator">|</span>')
                                  .prepend("<a id='sftheme' href='http://www.serverfault.com'><img src='" + icons.sf + "' title='Visit ServerFault' style='padding:1px'></a>")
                                  .prepend('<span class="link-separator">|</span>')
                                  .prepend("<a id='sutheme' href='http://superuser.com'><img src='" + icons.su + "' title='Visit SuperUser' style='padding:1px'></a>")
                                  .prepend('<span class="link-separator">|</span>')
                                  .prepend("<a id='sotheme' href='http://www.stackoverflow.com'><img src='" + icons.so + "' title='StackOverflow' style='padding:1px'></a>");
                }
})();
```

Comment: This is great, but what I'm suggesting would be a lot more powerful.  Especially if showed your current activity.

Answer (score 0):

This was asked earlier today to add links to the top and I believe it was denied (or at least everyone was against it). You already have the links displayed on the footer, and most people who are "power users" of the sites generally have them all bookmarked anyway.

Comment: Agreed... The GM script adds a nice way to do it, but I tend to think the other sites are already easy to get to with bookmarks and the footer.

Answer (score 0):

According to Jeff's response on [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2542/so-site-bar-minimalistic) it is something they are considering.