# I submitted a good question, just not a good fit for stackoverflow, I was told it would be migrated, but it was just removed. Can someone tell me why?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, migration, specific-question, deleted-questions

I submitted [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10149180/philosophically-why-cant-markup-be-binary-data-i-e-why-cant-we-compile-html), but was told it wasn't a good fit for stackoverflow--something I appreciate, I even commented on this in the question comments.

I was told it would be migrated to programming.stackexchange, but it looks like it's just been entirely removed, and with it my meager reputation. Can someone explain why it was removed instead of migrated?

Answer (score 9):

> I was told it would be migrated to programming.stackexchange

I assume you're referring to [Ken White's comment (10K Link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10149180/philosophically-why-cant-markup-be-binary-data-i-e-why-cant-we-compile-html#comment13015607_10149180)

Here it is below (emphasis mine)

> Off-topic here, I'm afraid. :) This is not a programming (code)
>   question; it's more theoretical, and therefore doesn't belong here.
>   **I've voted to migrate it to Programmers** where it may be a better fit.
>   (It's also inappropriate here because it can't be answered, and
>   therefore doesn't suit SO's Q & A format. The FAQ specifically
>   mentions this type of question as being inappropriate here.)

Ken may have voted to migrate but his vote wasn't enough as at least two other people voted to close it as off topic without migrating it.

Comment: Okay, understood. I suppose I read too much into that.

Answer (score 6):

I've taken a look at the question and, as it's worded now, it wouldn't be a good fit for Programmers.

It's very broad and academic. It's not really a practical question you currently face.

There are some questions that, while very good questions, just aren't a good fit for the Stack Exchange model. I think that this question - in it's present state - is one of those.

Comment: True. As a side note, the one who commented and voted for migration to programmers was probably the only one and the rest chose the general Off Topic option thus it wasn't migrated. Neither one of the [three](http://stackoverflow.com/users/246246/animuson) [who](http://stackoverflow.com/users/142162/tim-cooper) [deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/users/131433/bmargulies) it posted any comment.

Comment: That's fair enough. I suppose I'm a bit disappointed there isn't a single venue in the stackexchange universe where questions like this might live. Where else is there online you can ask a question and get so many interested eyes on a topic such as this? But I do take your point...

Comment: @Matt I feel your pain, but if SE allowed questions like yours they would drown out the on-topic, constructive questions and those "interested eyes" might leave. See [The chat room/forum problem](http://scobleizer.com/2009/11/02/the-chat-roomforum-problem-an-apology-to-technosailor/) [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) [Gorilla vs. Shark](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/) [Can the stack exchange system work with subjective and argumentative websites?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64311/148672)