# Why do we have more than one site to ask questions on?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Automatic/Central Question Sorting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68689/automatic-central-question-sorting)

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Trilogy Portal: Community Colloboration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6033/trilogy-portal-community-colloboration)

Why do we have more than one site to ask questions on?
Some users, like me, are registered on all 4 of these sites.
This requires me to switch tabs.

---

#### Suggestion:

Consolidate everything into one site.
When you ask a question, there should just be a DropDown list where you may specify what area it belongs.

That would be more sophisticated, I think.

Comment: I have made a suggestion regarding this over here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6033/trilogy-portal-community-colloboration

Comment: Possible Dublicate to a non working link?

Answer (score 1):

This was asked in the past. Less Noise.

You *could* create dropdowns to declare the nature of your question. And you *could* use dropdowns to declare what type of stuff you're interested in (Server stuff, Programming stuff, General Computer Stuff, Meta Stuff), but then you're really only reinventing the current method. Better just to keep them all distinct - which is what everybody would want if they were all merged to begin with.

I stay logged into all four, and use the [minimalistic-sister-site-toolbar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2542/so-site-bar-minimalistic) to jump around. It makes browsing all four very easy and nearly seemless.

Answer (score 0):

Several questions have been raised concerning this already. Just as a starter: [Business Portal proposal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6033/trilogy-portal-community-colloboration).
 There is even a tag for questions like this one: [trilogy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trilogy).