# Please make a "Recent Activity" page that shows all four site's activity

Tags: feature-request, recent-activity

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Trilogy Portal: Community Colloboration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6033/trilogy-portal-community-colloboration)
>   [Single location for SO/SF/SU user info](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/587/single-location-for-so-sf-su-user-info)

Between the 4 sites and the four "Recent Activity" pages, I have so many tabs open in my browser that it's getting hard to find them all. It would be nice if there was one "Recent Activity" page that showed all recent activity on all your linked accounts.

Comment: Sounds like a dupe to me: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/587/single-location-for-so-sf-su-user-info/

Comment: Dupe AAAAAAAAAAAHHHHHHHHHH: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6033 http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6070 http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6848

Comment: Don't overact, Eric. You could embarrass him ;)

Comment: Eric, most of those are asking for a single site.  I don't want a single site, I just want a single "Recent Activity".

Comment: John's link on the other hand is a dup.

Comment: This reminds me of my favorite Japanese giant-robot show: HYPER ULTRA MEGA DUPE GO!

Answer (score 2):

**[Obligatory call for StackOverflow API for people to do this themselves]**

Or just wait 6-8 weeks.

Comment: I planned to do this, but I'm not really interested at the moment.