# Automatic/Central Question Sorting

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, questions, stack-exchange, migration

I've noticed the Stack Exchange has grown immensely since its inception as Stack Overflow. As a result, I find asking questions in the right place here unnecessarily challenging. I'm wondering if you have thought about implementing a feature on the Stack Exchange central site where people ask the question there and either the scripts or staff/community members would sort the question to the right place.

Not sure if this would be too challenging or costly to implement. Just a thought to save your time while making users' lives easier.

Comment: It's not abundantly clear to me how "staff/community members sorting questions to the right place" is going to save their time :)

Answer (score 12):

If you're not willing to invest the small amount of time it takes to figure out where to ask your question -- the odds of your question being a good one are .. small.

It is improper to put the burden of "help me figure out where to ask" on the very experts you wish to answer your question.

Comment: True, but the number of portals on the Stackexchange these days is becoming overwhelming (hence the reason why I raised the question).