# Conversion of site network into concept net

Tags: feature-request

I think I have found something that will make everything intuitively easier for the users and the moderators.

There is a site called : http://conceptnet5.media.mit.edu

This is also open source, and once we have figured out how to interface the data from this site with the API, we can get a graphical representation of the concepts which becomes knowledge in this site.

In terms of classification, if you compare 2 concept trees for similarity, it will inidicate under which Stack Exchange site the question should be. We can also use heuristics.

Comment: We can also assign AI bots to handle closing bad questions, upvote good questions and suspend troublesome users. That will be the first and only Robotic Network in the world.

Comment: I'm not really clear on what you mean. What exacty would a " graphical representation of the concepts which becomes knowledge in this site." be

Comment: @RichardTingle It took me a while to understand: when creating a question, some algorithm would tell you which site your question should be posted to.

Comment: Isn't this essentially some of the detail that should really be part of your other request?

Comment: You people are underestimating what scientists are doing in their secret labs. Just because something is not on google doesn't mean it doesn't exist. In fact I think created a robotic network is actually a good idea, it will make things so much easier.

Comment: By all means, then. Build it.

Comment: I didn't say I know all the details myself, that is why I only know some of the pieces of the puzzle, but there are good chances that others will find the other pieces...

Comment: Just out of interest is there an API for this site, and are we allowed to make features for it ?

Comment: @YorkCleave $$$$ drives the world.  If someone made anything remotely as accurate as you seem to believe, they would have packaged it and sold it.  While it may be conceivable that such a thing exists, it is far from production ready and should not trusted in a real-world application.

Comment: @York [enter the rabbit hole here](http://stackapps.com/questions/1/api-documentation-and-help)

Comment: We should totally base our site design on what scientists are doing in their secret labs.

Comment: I have gotten so used to people completely misunderstanding what automated text processing is capable of that come the AI millennium I'm going to just dismiss it out of hand and be really, *really* surprised at what follows.

Answer (score 12):

I will quote Jeff:

> If you're not willing to invest the small amount of time it takes to figure out where to ask your question -- the odds of your question being a good one are .. small.

([Source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/68709/152859))

I second this opinion: deciding where to ask is task for the human being who is asking the question.

The system or some automated process can **suggest** sites, but not **decide**.

Comment: This proposal is not well-conceived, but in fairness to the OP, when Jeff stated that, there were a handful of sites, now there are over 100.  There does need to be a better mechanism to help users find sites for specific questions.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I agree, but like I said, only suggest sites not some 100% automatic process that actually decides where the question belongs and put it there.

Comment: @psubsee2003 as noted with the croissants, an identical question can be asked on 3 (or 4 if you count code golf) and be perfectly appropriate for each site and get different answers *depending on what the asker wants to get*.  Thus, part of the decision on what site to post on depends on the type of answer desired which is not articulated in the question itself.

Comment: A really simple algorithm could be to tally the individual words in the question and compare it to a lookup table, where the table has entries for the industry classification and common concepts underneath it. If 90% of the words fall under "programming" then it's most likely to be a programming question. But obviously this is a generalization, but it can be used as a guide. Maybe this, in combination with the moderator's discretion, can help to classify the question ?

Comment: @York what you currently suggest is turning the site decision to something 100% automatic. That won't work. If algorithm can help find the proper site **and only suggest it** (like you have suggested/related questions when typing new question) then it might be more popular and feasible request.

Comment: Yes if you look at my previous comment I said "Maybe this, in combination with the moderator's discretion...." The simple algorithm will give a probability of the question's classification.