# SO-Cubed - Nice

Tags: discussion, feature-request, usability

[image]

So the SO-Team took the minimalistic approach (Inspired by [SO-Site Bar (Minimalistic)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2542/so-site-bar-minimalistic)?) and implemented some "cubicons" (Is that a word?) representing each of the four so-sites. Next step, duplicate them at the top of the layout, so I don't have to scroll past a wall of questions just to find  a link to Meta :)

[image]

Comment: You will end up with non-linked cubicons (btw Google shows 582,000 hits).

Comment: Sorry, John. I don't follow. Why would I end up with non-linked cubicons? As long as the `href="http://meta.stackoverflow.com"` is there, all is well, no?

Comment: All those pipes are gone

Comment: The cubicons are not linked at the bottom of the page, the search icon is not linked. The envelope is the exception to the rule.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're doing it wrong. You're either supposed to have all these sites already bookmarked, or you're supposed to have your fingers trained to type it out faster than you can get to it via mouse click.

Or you can write a greasemonkey script that will take the entry <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Y</kbd> + <kbd>Ins</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd> and immediately take you to Meta.

**Edit** Cubicons would imply three dimensions. What you are looking at are Squares or Squaricons.

Comment: I firmly believe they are three-dimensional...they're just oriented in a way that makes you think otherwise ;)

Comment: @Jonathan Sampson: I disagree.  They're obviously hypercubicons, but we can only see one face of one cell.

Comment: @Pesto...oh, wait, I think I see what you're saying.... :)

Comment: They're not even really technically icons - they're actually characters ■

Comment: Three-dimensional characters....Kyle? :)

Comment: They are time cubes. Anything else would be evil.

Answer (score 5):

Little square unannotated icons are incredibly user unfriendly. I am offended that you would even consider suggesting something like this.

Comment: What if they have useful tooltips?  And when you aren't hovering over them, there's a huge blinking arrow pointing toward them with the text "THESE ARE USEFUL LINKS"?

Comment: We talking about icons that are expressed in the context of sister sites. It take a whole two seconds to figure that out. Consider your audience - the same audience that buys binary-clocks.

Comment: The context around a binary clock is simpler than the context around associating a coloured box with a website. I don't currently associate orange with SO, red with SF, cyan with SU and grey with Meta. While I might in the future, remembering something arbitrary like that is *making me think*, which seems very, very contrary to everything this family of sites represents.

Comment: Heaven-forbid you *think*.

Comment: Indeed. I thought the original greasemonkey idea was pretty stupid. At least what the team did in the footer is a bit better. But just supplying colored squares? Hell no.

Comment: When Welbog thinks, *people die.*

Comment: Making users think is a great way of making sure they never use your product.

Comment: The original greasemonkey script (Which Atwood called "Very Nice") currently has 10 favs, and over 20 upvotes. Apparently people don't mind *thinking* about "stupid" usability tools.

Comment: @Rich, sure, if you're developing a product for the average user. But we're not catering to your average user here.

Comment: Just because there are a lot of you doesn't mean you're not all wrong.

Comment: Ahh, I forgot 10-20 people represent the majority of the community now.

Comment: @Jonathon: What? I can't quite hear you. My greasemonkey script is still set to ignore.

Comment: @Welbog, that's a double-edged sword. I agree that this tool would be silly to implement on the next iPod, but we're talking about a community of users who memorize esoteric keystrokes, read binary clocks, and love non-cluttered screens. Considering the context, I like the minimalistic approach.

Comment: Minimalism isn't a good excuse to reduce usability. You're basically saying it's OK for programmers to make the #1 programming mistake (lack of usability) because the site is used by programmers. I can't believe you would suggest something like that. If anything, we ought to make sure SO is the most usable site *ever* simply because it's a place people go to learn to not make mistakes like this. Lead by example, Sampson.

Comment: To cover me claiming that usability is the #1 mistake: you realize there are people in the world who *hate programmers* because of things like this, right? It may not be a programming mistake *per se* but it's what end users notice the most, complain about the most and hate programmers for the most.

Comment: @Welbog: And obviously we have such a higher intelligence coming to the site. Especially to SuperUser, right?

Comment: @Rich B: I counted the fact that 99% of SO users are *awful* as an obvious truth.

Comment: @Welbog, the fact that end-users hate programmers because we make things hard is irrelevant. Again, SO is *for* programmers, not their parents. With regards to usability, I am of the persuasion that this particular feature is very usable. I've been using it since the start of July, along with many others - and I'm very pleased with it. You have to consider your audience. "Usable" is relative to what the user is capable of using to begin with. A cockpit control panel isn't very usable to me.

Comment: @Welbog: "It works for me! It must be great for everyone!"

Comment: IMO, this is a boost in usability. Sure, they're unfriendly to novice users, but they are very friendly for power users.  Novices can, and most likely would, safely ignore them.

Comment: @Rob, apparently the attitude here is that *everybody is stupid.*

Comment: @Rob: Sampson is advocating moving the links to the top, not copying them to the top. This suggestion is **bad**. Having links like that could be ignored, sure, as long as the current alternative remains the way it is.

Comment: @Rob: Sounds like something that should be kept as optional via greasemonkey then. SuperUser is for people who can't figure out simple stuff on a computer.

Comment: @Welbog, I'm not suggesting removing them from the footer! I've *never* said that. I want to see them up top, and in the footer.

Comment: @Sampson: What does the word "move" mean in your world? To a programmer, it means "take from one place and put somewhere else, obliterating the original". Consider your audience when choosing words. If you meant copy, you should say copy. I'm more or less OK with the idea of copying them to the top.

Comment: This comment thread has been nothing but a subliminal ploy for you to all buy more binary clocks. And those squares ignore the colour-blind or those unable to differentiate between two similiar hues, as mentioned here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10938/ - binary clocks, pfft, hex clocks are the real deal.

Comment: The usability would increase dramatically if you replaced squares with the colored acronyms like "SO" "SF" etc. the usability would go up and wouldn't prove to be completely useless to someone who has difficulties differentiating colors.

Comment: @Rich, SuperUser (as the name implies) was for "SuperUsers," but you rightly point out that it has become a pool of noobish interaction. I've almost completely stopped-visiting as a result. That being said, I still think they're smart enough to handle cubicons, or to safely-ignore them as Rob suggested.

Comment: @jonathan - Everyone here _is_ stupid in their own special way. Personally I think the current layout will cause trouble for non-Technical users once they find SuperUser and/or Stack Exchange starts to open up a broader audience. I usually agree with @Welbog on these sorts of things. The boxes we're talking about here though are purely a power user tool. Most of the people who would find them confusing are not likely to be on all 4 sites with any regularity and therefore unlikely to care.

Comment: @Welbog, you're right. I've corrected the wording. Thanks.

Comment: @Jonathon: What? I can't quite hear you. My greasemonkey script is still set to ignore.

Comment: +1 for the OP proving the opposing point in his discussion.

Comment: @Sampson: Your suggestion is still awful. The icons should have shapes and/or words for easy differentiation, good titles for screen readers. Colour-to-site relationships are a bad idea. Every site has a logo, so why not use those instead? The logos are already associated with the sites, so there's no learning curve. The logos are shaped differently so colourblind users can use them. (Except meta's logo. That will have to be changed.)

Comment: @Rich B - Congrats, your greasemonkey ignore comment was the first I ever wanted to downvote into oblivion.

Comment: The OP didn't point out his problem with "moving" the links. Had he done so, I would have conceded the point immediately and fixed my wording as I am readily admitting my mistake there.

Comment: @Rob: Good, now you are on my list!

Comment: @Welbog, take it as a concept, not a full-end solution. After submitting my minimalistic suggestion, others modified it to include icons.

Comment: @Welbog - that's a good evolution of the mini-icon concept. I agree the color associations could be an issue. I would support a logo-based icon solution once the meta logo gets some differentiation.

Comment: +1 for the OP not knowing he is the OP. Once again proving the point that not everyone understands computers and basic lingo.

Comment: @Rich - There should be a badge for getting on your list.

Comment: @Welbog/Rob The most up-voted response to my minimalistic script is an icon-version: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2542/so-site-bar-minimalistic

Comment: @Rob: The meta icon shouldn't even be present. It should only be on the feedback link. Meta is not part of the 'trilogy'.

Comment: @Rich, no, not everybody understands you.

Comment: @Rich, we're discussing this within the comments of an answer, not the question. It's a matter of Scope at this point. OP in this scope is referring (to me at least) to the author of our context, this answer.

Comment: @Rob: Not really, having a greasemonkey script to ignore users is nothing that should ever be rewarded, only punished.

Comment: @Jonathon: What? I can't quite hear you. My greasemonkey script is still set to ignore.

Comment: @Rob The ignore-user script is self-rewarding. It's rewarding-enough *not* to seeing the clear trolling of certain users.

Comment: The *true* reward comes with installing the script and then not putting any users in its list. So it's always there, carefully ignoring *no one*. When i'm feeling down, doubting myself, i can then point my cursor at that little Greasemonkey icon and say to myself, "See? TOLERANT AND ACCEPTING OF OTHERS! GOOD!!!"

Comment: @Shog9, the current state of my installation ;)

Comment: @Shog9, That is, until somebody becomes so annoying that I have no desire to tolerate their form of participation. It's all a matter of signal and noise. You clearly cannot tolerate everybody - some here are very intolerant of those who wish to have ignore-scripts.

Comment: Whooooooooooosh.

Comment: @Rich, was that the sound of something flying right over Jonathan's head?

Comment: @jjnguy: I do believe it was.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an update to your script that uses the same order and colors as the team's approach:

```
$('#hlinks')
      .prepend('<span class="link-separator"> | </span>')
      .prepend("<a href='http://blog.stackoverflow.com' style='position:relative;top:1px;display:inline-block;width:10px;height:10px;background:#444;margin-right:1px;' title='Blog'><span style='display:none'>blog</span></a>")
      .prepend("<a href='http://meta.stackoverflow.com' style='position:relative;top:1px;display:inline-block;width:10px;height:10px;background:#969696;margin-right:7px;' title='Meta'><span style='display:none'>meta.stackoverflow</span></a>")
      .prepend("<a href='http://www.superuser.com' style='position:relative;top:1px;display:inline-block;width:10px;height:10px;background:#00AFEF;margin-right:7px' title='Super User'><span style='display:none'>superuser</span></a>")
      .prepend("<a href='http://www.serverfault.com' style='position:relative;top:1px;display:inline-block;width:10px;height:10px;background:#E8272C;margin-right:7px' title='Server Fault'><span style='display:none'>serverfault</span></a>")
      .prepend("<a href='http://www.stackoverflow.com' style='position:relative;top:1px;display:inline-block;width:10px;height:10px;background:#FE7A15;margin-right:7px' title='Stack Overflow'><span style='display:none'>stackoverflow</span></a>")
```