# Links to other portals at the top of the page

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow, superuser, serverfault

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SO-Site Bar (Minimalistic)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2542/so-site-bar-minimalistic)

It could be nice if the links to the other portals were easier to acces. Maybe as a dropdown at the top of the page.

Comment: Links? I already have Firefox tabs dedicated for all sites!

Comment: Dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2542/so-site-bar-minimalistic

Comment: @john: dupe problem, different solution ;)

Comment: That's right, Johannse, but Jeff already indicated in the dupe, that he want to implement it. So your suggestion is betting on a dead horse ;)

Comment: @john: Whats wrong with beating a dead horse? :P