# Hop Between associated sites more easily?

Tags: feature-request, linked-accounts

Shouldn't we be able to hop between associated sites more easily? If I am in the middle of perusing StackOverflow, and a great meta question occurs to me shouldn't there be a link say in the header, to take me there, since my accounts are linked, I've already authenticated via opeid, etc. I've done it by going to from stackoverflow->quesions to StackOverflow-> profile to meta->profile to meta->questions, but that's the long way around the barn.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the links at the bottom of every page.  Since you are logged in already, you can hop between them quickly. Click link at bottom, go to profile. Or you can create bookmarks to your profiles. I like your idea, but how are you proposing to make this process quicker exactly?

Comment: Well first, I didn't realize before, that when I hop from profile page to profile page, that I wasn't logged in on the second sight. But since my accounts are linked and I have already authenticated to the first site, why can't I be authenticated to the second sight automatically, SO single-signon? It can be via the links at the bottom if you want, though I did not notice them until your mention. Putting something that useful below stuff like "privacy policy", and "contact us" is a good way to hide it in plain site. I would put it in the header between the link to your profile and logout.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Firefox and/or Greasemonkey, [check out this greasemonkey script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5933/greasemonkey-script-to-show-profile-reputation-and-badges-from-all-so-sites-in). I use it, and find myself a bit confused when I log into a SOFU site and it *isn't* there.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using [an alternate Greasemonkey script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2542/so-site-bar-minimalistic) to [the one Jared mentioned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31922/hop-between-associated-sites-more-easily/31941#31941). It takes up a bit less space.