# Switch between common network websites?

Tags: feature-request, usability

Is that possible to switch between common network web sites like stackoverflow, area51... with a way that is common between all sites?

Like for example a hover list at the logo of each site?

Comment: let's see how long our grease-monkey wielding readers take to sort that out (ideally via http://stackauth.com/0.9/sites)....

Comment: Perhaps http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/842/stackoverflow-sister-sites/905#905 will suit your needs? It is probably outdated, though.

Comment: I agree, I am active mainly on stackoverflow but increasingly active on Database Administrators.  Switching between them requires me to either navigate to my profile and clicking on one of my accounts (two to three clicks).  Or typing it into the address bar.  That's far less than ideal.