# Easy navigation between StackExchange-2.0 websites

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, usability, stackexchange-2.0

Now that I'm participating in 3 stackexchange 2.0 sites, and the 3 original SO sites, it gets really hard to remember to visit every one of these sites to check for activity. If you factor in meta sites, that's an extra 4 sites I need to check. I know about email notifications, but for things such as comments, you don't get email but do get a notification.

I propose some kind of drop down on the top left which will show you the sites you are a member of. Some ideas for sorting the list are: based on reputation, alphabetical, or user-customizable. It would be very useful to see a notification icon (mail icon) next to each one too.

This is similar to, and would replace, my other feature request: [Easy navigation between meta and "parent" site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55551/easy-navigation-between-meta-and-parent-site). It's also similar to [Easy Navigation Between Stackoverflow Family-Sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/842/easy-navigation-between-stackoverflow-family-sites), except that this is for all StackExchange sites.

Comment: I guess this would be an alternative to putting notifications from all SE/trilogy sites in the notification bar at the top? Because I know that's been suggested a few times.

Comment: I configure Chrome to open each of them in tabs on startup.

Comment: Not just for the trilogy sites, all the sites, and let it be configurable so the user who posts all over SO doesn't get a bug wall of notification bars.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Until they reach *public* beta, there's no point in linking Stack Exchange 2.0 sites together.

Remember, during the ~7 day private beta only whitelisted users who committed to the [Area 51 site proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com) will have access to that particular site.

Edit: all public betas are now linked in the footer, like so:

http://img14.imageshack.us/img14/4296/image1tx.png

A more comprehensive "network branding" sort of thing is coming soon-ish.

Comment: That's pretty cool. Although, I think it would help limit the clutter if it listed only the sites that you are a member of.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Google Chrome, I would recommend the [Stack Overflow Notifier extension](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38544/stack-overflow-notifier-chrome-extension). It shows up as a little icon next to the address bar, and automatically detects Stack Exchange sites when you're on your recent activity page. The icon changes to let you know about activity on all of the sites you have added.

http://img153.imageshack.us/img153/6279/chromec.png

It currently just does a page scrape, but hopefully it will be updated to use the API.

Comment: I strongly reccomend getting it up to date with the API because then you can enter to win prizes :D

Answer (score 0):

[Insert plug for my Stack Exchange aggregator here](https://stackapps.com/questions/570/saggregator-a-way-to-accumulate-all-the-latest-activity-from-the-stackapps-api)

Comment: This is pretty cool, but because I don't bother to read instructions or descriptions, I thought it was going to be like a Stack Exchange dashboard, rather than just a listing of recent activity on the chosen sites.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not very good at marketing or choosing good names... comes with the territory of being a technical person.